# n^(-1/3) vs (n!) ^ 2 vs 2 ^ (n^2). Factorial square or exponential with index( n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Which is a better function complexity wise: `n^(-1/3)` vs `(n!) ^ 2` vs `2 ^ (n^2)`?

Sterling's approximation would give `n! -> nlogn` so would it get converted into `n^2 (log n)^2`.

Comment: Inverse of third root can be found using a simple recursive method, I should think that it is the fastest/least complex. I think that logarithm implementations use the iterative power-series expansion, which itself uses factorial. Factorial can be optimized to have better than O(n) speed. My guess would be that n!^2 would be better (and more accurate) than (nlogn)^2. Don't take my word for it though.

Comment: This is like asking "which is better: (1) a million dollars or (2) having your foot nailed to the floor?"

Comment: If you have an algorithm that solves some problem in non-constant sublinear time without preprocessing, I need to see that please.

Comment: Perhaps you mean n^(1/3)?  That would at least be an increasing function.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your interpretation of Sterling's approximation is incorrect. `ln(n!) -> O(n log n)`. `n!` itself is far closer to exponential time complexity.

Secondly, the answer here should be fairly obvious. However, if you aren't sure, just start plugging in some numbers for `n`:

```
10^(-1/3) = 0.464, (10!)^2 = 13168189440000, 2^(10^2) = 2^100
```

It should be easy to see from the above.

Comment: Yes I tried that but when the index is negative the values are decreasing.So it is growing fast but if it is compared to theta(n) . theta (n) is better right?

Comment: The values are decreasing as the input size gets bigger. Hence it's not growing at all, it's *shrinking*. I've no idea what you mean by `theta(n)` being "better".

Comment: `n!` is not just "far closer" to exponential complexity, it's between `2^n` and `2^(n log n)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume `n^(-1/3)` is a typo and ignore it.

To compare the other two, we can take their logarithms:

```
log( (n!)^2 ) = 2 log(n!) = Theta(n log n)
log( 2^(n^2) ) = n^2 log 2 = Theta(n^2)
```

So `(n!)^2 << 2^(n^2)`.